# How to integrate a html code and widgets into a picture

Tags: html, widget, image

I want to introduce/insert  a html code and a widget into a picture, something like a paypal button and a time coundown . In witch way  it is possible to do that ?. 
I appreciate every answer. Please give me some tips.

Answer (score 0):

Give some other clues mate.
From what you rote, I think that you can accomplish that just with a little css.
Let's say, the image on css's z-index 5, and the content that you want to place over it on z-index 6, 7, 10, doesn't mind as long it's greater than the z-index of the image.

Then, the counter, just google a little and you'll find plenty tutorials about javascript countdowns.

Comment: Thanks Pablo for your answer... i wanna introduce this bar http://jsfiddle.net/WawPr/ to a picture like this for example: http://s017.radikal.ru/i441/1301/5e/e74b867930c8.jpg . Please help me with a example or a tutorial ...

Answer (score 0):

As I said. Use z-index css propperty.
Take a div, set it to the image exact size, then with margins and z-index, place the counter on top of it.

As an example:

```
<div id="image">
   <div id="progress"> ... </div>
</div>
```

Where the css for each would be:

```
#image{
   width: 400px;
   height: 500px;
   z-index: 0;
}

#progress {
   z-index:10;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

The width and height propperties should be the image's size ones. The rest it's up to where excactly are you gonna place this code.

Comment: DO i have to make different files for html and css code ( http://jsfiddle.net/WawPr/) or to introduce the entire code in one index.html file ?

Comment: The best practice is to have css in a file appart. But will work both ways

Comment: I'm sorry to disturb you another time but i failed to do that you told me . When i open the index.html file i receive a blank page only with text on it. It's the first time for me to do such think and it is difficult ... if it is not a problem for you can you help me with full code :  Here is the photo : http://s017.radikal.ru/i437/1301/22/d925560cebce.jpg  ..... and here the code for the bar : http://jsfiddle.net/WawPr/398/ ... I would really appreciate your help! Thanks

Comment: Just post here the code you're using, so i can see how you want to present it.